# Typescript: is there any difference between using getter and normal function

Tags: typescript

Let's say i have a class and i have declared two methods to be used only in this class.

```
// 1.
private get something() { return 0; }

// 2.
private getSomething() { return 0; }
```

I know about getters and setters but just i am curious if there is any difference in this case?

Comment: A private getter doesn't make any sense. The entire point of a getter is to provide (controlled) access from outside the class to a private member. It must be public to achieve this goal.

Comment: *"I know about getters and setters but just i am curious if there is any difference in this case?"* -- there is a big difference. The first one is a getter for the `something` property of the object, the second one is a method named `something`. Different concepts, different ways to access and use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the syntax you use to get the value

```
class Test {
    private get something() { return 0; }

    private getSomething() { return 0; }
    public doStuff(){
        console.log(this.something); // invokes the defined getter but looks like a field not a method call 
        console.log(this.getSomething())
    }
}
```

Also behind the scenes the `get/set` syntax is syntactic sugar for `Object.defineProperty`.